# Merging reusable block in YAML (Symfony framework)

Tags: symfony, yaml, config

In Symfony I try to merge a block of YAML from `parameters.yml` to `config.yml`. My question is how I can store some configurations in Symfony 3.4 and then insert into my config file. For now I got an error:

> In Parser.php line 290:
>     Reference "'%insurance%'" does not exist at line 188 (near "<<: 
>     *'%insurance%'").

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    Insurance: &insurance
    list:
        title: '<strong>Ubezpieczenia</strong>'
        sort: ['sequence', 'ASC']
        fields:
            - { property: 'sequence', label: 'Kolejność'}
            - { property: 'title', label: 'Tytuł'}
            - { property: 'description', label: 'Opis'}
        form:
            fields:
                - { property: 'title', type: 'text', label: 'Tytuł'}
                - { property: 'description', type: 'ckeditor', label: 'Opis',
                    type_options: { config_name: 'simple_config' }}
                - { property: 'sequence', type: 'integer', label: 'Kolejność'}
```

config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
easy_admin:
    [...]
    entities:
        [...]
        MotorInsurance:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\MotorInsurance
            label: menu.motorInsurance
            <<: *'%insurance%'
```

> [...] there are non-related configurations

Am I did something wrong when I am calling `Inusrance` block?

Comment: Try to change `<<: *'%insurance%'` into `<<: *insurance` (quotes and percent sign removed) in your config.yml file.

Comment: I tried this before, and it wasn't work. I think @xabbuh is right, but his solution won't work in Symfony, becouse it parsing `config.yml` only for extensions

Answer (score 2):

So I try again and @xabbuh was right. I forgot that I have also block for parameters in my `config.yml`. My file now look like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: pl
    Insurance: &insurance
        list:
            title: '<strong>Ubezpieczenia</strong>'
            sort: ['sequence', 'ASC']
            fields:
                - { property: 'sequence', label: 'Kolejność'}
                - { property: 'title', label: 'Tytuł'}
                - { property: 'description', label: 'Opis'}
        form:
            fields:
                - { property: 'title', type: 'text', label: 'Tytuł'}
                - { property: 'description', type: 'ckeditor', label: 'Opis',
                    type_options: { config_name: 'simple_config' }}
                - { property: 'sequence', type: 'integer', label: 'Kolejność'}
easy_admin:
[...]
entities:
    [...]
    MotorInsurance:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\MotorInsurance
        label: menu.motorInsurance
        <<: *insurance
```

And this works fine :) also everything can be overriden for your minds.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. Different files are parsed independently so you cannot reuse a reference defined in one YAML file in another YAML file.

The solution would be to place all the config that is required in the same file.